# VB.net need to Override in parameter from C# library

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to inherit from the C# Sampler class from OpenTelemetry.Trace into VB.net class.

When I use Visual Studio to auto implement the abstract class it provides the following code below, however I can't find "IsReadOnlyAttribute" in any dll for any .net framework 4.6.2 which is what our project is using.

Searching online finds me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.isreadonlyattribute.-ctor?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.6.2 which shows that this attribute exists in "System.Runtime.CompilerServices" which is available on in  4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8.

Is there another way to make this work or do I need to upgrade our project?

Cheers

```
Imports OpenTelemetry.Trace
Public Class ConfigurableSampler
  Inherits Sampler

  Public Overrides Function ShouldSample(<IsReadOnlyAttribute> ByRef samplingParameters As SamplingParameters) As SamplingResult
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
  End Function 
End Class
```

So Today I updated to .Net framework 4.8 but I still get an error in VB
[image]

To find out if this was to do with the parameters or the "in" modifier I added a function as per below which shows that this does work and the issue is still with the "in" parameter modifier.

```
Public Function Test(ByRef samplingParameters As SamplingParameters) As SamplingResult
    Return New SamplingResult(True)
End Function
```

I am wondering if this a defect of C# to VB or some limitation I am hitting.

Comment: You may have to define your derived class in a C# library project and then reference that in your VB project. That said, I think that targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 might limit the C# language version you can use, so you might not be able to use `in`. In that case, maybe you can target .NET Standard. If OpenTelemetry.Trace uses `in` and supports .NET Framework 4.6.2 then there must be a way to do it.

Comment: I just tried adding the equivalent of your class to a C# project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 and it worked fine with the `in` keyword. You should either upgrade to a newer version in your current project - you probably ought to anyway, unless there's a specific reason not to - or else add a C# library specifically for this type.

Comment: Nobody else has this problem, a bit odd.  You're stuck in vb.net, it just doesn't have the plumbing to override this method correctly.  Nothing you can do but do it in C#.  Arguably this is a design mistake in the library, I'd file a bug report.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney, you are correct the best path forward for me here was to create a C# adapter class and then reference that dll in the VB project thank you. Create that as an answer and I will accept that. Cheers

Comment: hey @HansPassant, I log a report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VBNet-using-C-dll-with-overrides-funct/10211453

Comment: I'm happy for you to add your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best path forward that I found here was to create the following class in a C# project and then reference this in the VB.net project.

```
  public abstract class SamplerAdapter : Sampler
  {
    public override SamplingResult ShouldSample(in SamplingParameters samplingParameters)
    {
      return ShouldSampleAdapter(samplingParameters);
    }

    public abstract SamplingResult ShouldSampleAdapter(SamplingParameters samplingParameters);
  }
```